# DHCP loop in windows r2 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

i have a problem with a windows r2 2008
is not even booting, this is the output

Attempting boot fom NIC

Client MAC x.x.x.x GUID: x.x.x.x

DHCP........\

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: thanks for your quickly response, i love you men! i cannot find how to rate your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not Windows - it's your NIC PXE driver. If you don't need to PXE boot, go into your BIOS or your NIC configurator and disable PXE boot.